# `if` condition only working for first div encountered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to swap out one class for another when a page loads depending on the directory in the URL. My code is working for the first `div` in my menu, but not for any others. Here's the code:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    pathname = pathname.replace('/MVC/', '');

    if (pathname == $('.navitem').attr('rel')) {
        $('.navitem[rel='+pathname+']').toggleClass('navitem selected_menu')
    }
});
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="navitem" rel="dashboard"><a href="http://localhost/MVC/dashboard">Dashboard</a></div>
<div class="navitem" rel="chat"><a href="http://localhost/MVC/chat">Chat</a></div>
<div class="navitem" rel="users"><a href="http://localhost/MVC/user">Users</a</div>
```

When I `alert($('.navitem').attr('rel'))`, it always returns the `rel` value of the first `div`. How do I get it to look at all of them instead of just the first one?

Comment: Here come 10 answers, all using .each().

Comment: why don't you just take out the if statement and keep the inner toggleClass statement? wouldn't that find all elements with the class "navitem" and "rel" attribute equal to pathname...then toggle each of their classes?

Comment: i still don't see why you need to filter or use if statements. just use your line in the if statement ONLY: $('.navitem[rel='+pathname+']').toggleClass('navitem selected_menu');

If no elements match, no classes get toggled. I would think simply using selectors would be the best and fastest way. Using filter, or each, or anything else adds to something you don't need to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just use one comparison operation because you have to check all of the `div`s.

```
$(".navitem").filter(function() {
  return $(this).attr("rel") === pathname;  // filter out the correct one(s)
}).toggleClass("navitem selected_menu");
```

By the way, it is usually `$(document).ready`. Although it doesn't matter what you pass to `$` in case of `.ready`, this is the de facto standard.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm just learning jQuery, so I apologize. Thanks for the tip about $(document).ready as well!

Comment: @John Zetterman: No need to apologise, this is what this site is for :) Please don't forget to accept the answer that was the solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to loop through them using each:

```
$('.navitem').each(function(){
    if (pathname == $(this).attr('rel')) {
        $(this).toggleClass('navitem selected_menu')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a loop. Try this:

```
$(".navItem").each(function () {
    if (pathname == $(this).attr('rel')) {
        $(this).toggleClass('navitem selected_menu')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to check for anything, let the selector do it all.

```
$('navitem[rel=' + pathname + ']').toggleClass('navitem selected_menu');
```

Don't even include the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the .each method of JQuery to test all of your matching elements.  Like this:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    pathname = pathname.replace('/MVC/', '');

    $('.navitem').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('rel') == pathname) {
            $(this).toggleClass('selected_menu');
        }
    });

});
```